# Ctrl+C does not work in chrome, but works outside of it

Tags: google-chrome

I could not use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** to copy texts in Google Chrome from some days ago. But I can do it outside of Chrome. What's the matter ?

It happened after installing an extension. I removed it, but the problem did not solve

Comment: Maybe some extension is to blame? Does it work when all extensions are disabled?

Comment: @vasa1 it happened after installing an extension. I removed it, but the problem did not solve

Comment: Which platform are you on? Linux, Mac, Windows, other?

Comment: You may consider making a [new profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059).

Answer (score 2):

You can [reset your](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?p=ui_reset_settings&hl=en&rd=1) browser settings

> Resetting your browser settings will reset the unwanted changes
>   caused by installing other programs. However, your saved bookmarks and
>   passwords will not be cleared or changed.

Or there is an exstension [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf/related) here, you can look for all shortcuts (by clicking ***"All shortcuts list"** and find what for is **CRTL+C** used now, and edit it in URL patren put COPY, or delete it, and it shold go back to default browser action : **COPY**

Comment: The link `Shortcut Manager` link is `404` now.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it may be an extension. Reinstalling chrome once in a while with only verified extensions is a good practice. Also, try CRTL+INS instead of CRTL+C. It may work even in a bad extension scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in Chrome on Windows 10 just now.   The problem went away after I closed all instances of Chrome browser and restarted Chrome browser.